# Using ZBar barcode scanner in Android, how can I show the user the barcode that was just scanned? E.g. show the four corners of the barcode

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner

I have integrated the Zbar barcode scanner into my Android application. I'm very impressed with this compared to others I have tried. It's quick and very accurate. The only thing I do not like about it is that by default there is no indication that the barcode gets scanned. I would like to display either a rectangle or even just a line across the barcode after it has been scanned just so it's easier to see what exactly the app scanned. Even if I have to manually draw a rectangle based on the location of the found barcode that would be fine but can't seem to figure it out. Does anyone know how this can be done? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use frame layout to place rectangle image transparent inside on scanner camera

Comment: @Kat-hat I understand how to get the rectangle there, that's not an issue. In order to get the correct size for the rectangle and where to place it on the View, I need to know the location of the barcode that was found.